# Create new Object from XSD in ESQL

Tags: websphere

Is there a way to create an object whose format is defined in a message model?

Actually, I have created a message model with some fields containing default values and some restrictions. I managed with the following code to create a message in ESQL, but the other fields (which contain default values) do not appear :

```
CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN('DFDL');
-- SET OutputRoot.Properties = InputRoot.Properties;      
SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageSet = '{ObjectsDefinitionLibrary}';
SET OutputRoot.Properties.MessageType = '{}:Example1MsgModel';
SET OutputRoot.DFDL.Example1MsgModel.record[1].FieldOne = 'Value1';
```

Will this be possible with ESQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is there a way to create an object whose format is defined in a message model

You need to define what you mean by 'object'. Do you want to create a message tree based on the model? Or do you want to generate a valid BLOB from the model?

As has been said by others, if you want to generate a BLOB from a DFDL model, you must ensure that everything in the message model (including complex elements) has minOccurs>=1, and you must provide a default value for every field.
If you want a message tree then you will need to parse that BLOB using the DFDL parser. Which leads nicely into the answer to your other question...

> > Will this be possible with ESQL?

ESQL does not offer a special statement to create a message tree from a model. However, it does offer two functions for parsing and writing any BLOB/message tree. Look up the ASBITSTREAM function, and the CREATE function (with the PARSE clause).